# Woher kommt das "Lachkätherle"?

Tags: etymology, dialect, proverb, swabian

Meine Großmutter (aus Schwaben) hatte immer einen ganz bestimmten Ausdruck, den sie zu einem besonders ausgelassenen und fröhlichen jungen Mädchen benutzte:

> Du bisch aber ein **Lachkätherle**!

Nun habe ich das weder in einem Wörterbuch noch in der Literatur finden können.

Daher jetzt meine Frage, wo der Ausdruck wohl herkommt, und ob man diesen in Schwaben oder auch in anderen deutschsprechenden Gegenden heute noch kennt oder versteht.

Comment: "Kätherle" wird von "Katharina" kommen. Was aber eine Lach-Katharina ist, weiß ich auch nicht.

Comment: ... allerdings scheint mir, dass "Katharina" (oder Ableitungen von diesem Namen) früher oft verwendet wurden, um Mädchen generell zu bezeichnen. Sie auch die *Heulsuse*. Möglicherweise ist Lach-Kätherle entstanden in Analogie zur Heulsuse?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: das Kätherle ist auch eine Figur im *Spiegelschwaben*. Wohl ein vor allem im 19. Jhdt. gebräuchlicher Kosename für Katharina/Käthe.

Comment: Ja, dass Kätherle = Katharina ist, ist unstrittig. Ich habe oder hatte auch einige Tanten etc. im schwäbischen Zweig der Familie, die so genannt wurden. Die Frage wäre, gibt es eine aufspürbare Zitierung für "Lachkathrin" oder so?

Comment: Weitere Bildung nach diesem Muster: die *flotte Lotte* (ein Küchengerät). Dann noch das *Funkenmariechen*... insgesamt haben wir es hier wohl mit rhetorischen Formen aus dem Felde der Synekdoche zu tun: Man nehme einen beliebigen Mädchennamen, meine jedoch "Mädchen" ganz allgemein.

Comment: Je mehr ich darüber nachdenke - *Lachkätherle* als Antonym zu *Heulsuse* gefällt mir richtig gut.

Comment: ... was aber die Frage erhebt, wo nun eigentlich die *Heulsuse* herkommt.

Comment: Da es sich um Schwäbisch handelt, kann die angegebene Schreibweise auch ganz anders sein. Ich halte es für sehr unwahrscheinlich, dass der Ausdruck etwas mit dem Namen Katharina zu tun hat. Im Schwäbischen gibt es eine Redewendung: "Schau, die Aschdrid, des isch dem Rudi sei Käddr." Dabei ist Rudi z. B. der Vater und Astrid seine Tochter. Käddr oder Ketter oder anders ist die liebevolle Bezeichnung für ein Mädele=Mädchen. Es wäre schön, wenn sich native speaker aus dem Ländle dazu äußern würden.

Comment: @Harald. In der Tat, deine These ist extrem plausibel. "Käddr" ist zwar auch nicht in meinem aktiven Wortschatz, aber jetzt, da du es erwähnst, erinnere ich mich, dass meine oberschwäbische dörfliche Verwandtschaft diesen Ausdruck durchaus benutzt(e).

Comment: Das Kätherle ist eine Figur in den [Abenteuern der sieben Schwaben](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/abenteuer-der-sieben-schwaben-und-des-spiegelschwaben-2006/1), dort auch in genau dieser Schreibweise *Käther* genannt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eine abschließende Antwort auf die Frage, wo der Begriff "Lachkätherle" (Schreibweise kann auch anders sein) herkommt, ist, wie es scheint, noch nicht möglich. Es kamen über die Kommentare aber einige gute Gedanken, die ich hier zusammenfasse und mit einer kleinen Bibliotheks- und Zeitzeugenrecherche ergänze.

**Vorschlag 1:**

Lachkätherle könnte eine kontrastierende Parallelbildung zu

> Heulsuse

sein, wobei ein verbreiteter Mädchenname (hie Suse/Susanne, hie Kathrin/Katharina/Käthe) im Sinne einer Synekdoche für "Mädchen" steht.

"Käther" als Variante (Koseform) von Katharina ist im dörflichen Dialekt üblich und übrigens auch literarisch belegbar, z.B. in Ludwig Aurbachers (1785-1874) *Abenteuer der sieben Schwaben und des Spiegelschwaben* (Link dazu siehe Takkats Kommentar unten), hier v.a. das Kapitel *Wie die sieben Schwaben einem Mägdlein begegnen, und wie der Blitzschwab von ihr auf die Kirbe geladen wird*.

**Vorschlag 2:**

"Kätherle" in "Lachkätherle" kommt nicht (direkt?) von Katharina, sondern von

> Käddr

(Schreibung wieder unklar; "Kätter", "Ketter" etc. wären möglich), was ein alter Ausdruck für "Mädchen" (oder "Tochter"?) ist, den ich in der Tat bei dörflicher Verwandtschaft in Oberschwaben auch schon in freier Wildbahn gehört habe.

Allerdings wäre zu fragen, ob nicht auch "Käddr" in diesem Sinne letztlich von "Katharina" kommt.

**Ein Blick ins Buch**

Ich hatte einige Hoffnung gesetzt, eine Antwort zu finden in *Hermann Wax: Etymologie des Schwäbischen. Geschichte von mehr als 6000 schwäbischen Wörtern. 3. Auflage*, jedoch, überraschenderweise findet sich darin weder ein Eintrag zu "Käddr" (in welcher Schreibung auch immer) noch zu "Lachkxxxx".

Der nächste Versuch wäre zu unternehmen mit der neusten Auflage des genannten Werkes, nun unter dem Namen "Geschichte von mehr als 8000 schwäbischen Wörtern". Diese Ausgabe ist mir im Moment leider nicht zugänglich.

**Zeitzeugenbefragung**

Mein Vater, Jahrgang 1939, aufgewachsen im ländlichen Oberschwaben, kennt den Begriff "Lachkätherle" (Schreibung unbekannt) ebenfalls. Er würde ihn verwenden vornehmlich für Mädchen fröhlichen Gemüts. Auf meine Frage, ob auch gestandene Frauen  als "Lachkätherle" bezeichnet werden könnten, meinte er: Ja, das könne man durchaus auch tun.

Comment: Schöne Antwort! Es fehlt zum Vorschlag 2 noch ein Zitat aus den [sieben Schwaben](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/abenteuer-der-sieben-schwaben-und-des-spiegelschwaben-2006/1) mit der **Käther** / dem **Kätherle** und dann akzeptiere ich die Antwort.

Comment: Ich würde warten mit dem Akzeptieren der Antwort. Immerhin gibt es noch 2000 Chancen, bei Hermann Wax im neueren Buch, eine Expertenmeinung zu finden.